# Language localization only working in debug mode

Tags: c#, localization, multilingual, visual-studio-debugging

I have setup support for multiple languages in my application. I have localized the form, set all labels and also built my resX files holding the translated messages. This all works fine while running it in debug mode from within Visual Studio, but when I run the "Release" version outside of Visual Studio, it will not change the language.

My main question is: Is this happening because I don't have that specific language installed on my system? Will it change language for someone who has Windows installed in that language still? Or if they have that language installed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run your application in release, you mean starting the .exe? If so, please validate that the directory you are in have the folder of each language.

For example, if your application is by default in english and that you offer french support, you should have a folder called "fr" which contains the ressource dll for your application.

If you don't, I think it will default to the base language of your application.

Comment: Ah that was it, Thanks alot. In that case, is there a way to embed the .dll inside the application as an embedded resource? I will accept your answer in a few mins when it lets me.

Comment: I don't know if you can emmbedded it in one big dll, sorry. But if you do a deployment project, it should detect it as a dependency and copy it along with the exe.

Comment: Thanks alot. I'm trying to keep it a single .exe if I can and extract everything from there if it's needed, but now it's starting to look like I will have to use an installer or package in a .zip.